Spring boot custom autoconfiguration - missing metadata file in target
In my spring boot 3.2.4 application I am trying to create a custom spring boot starter, with auto configuration. I have been following the spring documentation here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/developing-auto-configuration.html
And now I am trying to get the preprocessor to create the metadata json file in my taget "META-INF", such that other projects can rely on the property documentation, but for some reason the file is not created. The preprocessor works fine inside the project itself, there I can see the auto complete in the "application.yml" file.
I am using maven, my starter is a child module to a parent POM that uses spring-boot-starter-parent as its parent, and have tried to add in the annotation preprocessor in my build, and all tutorials I find, only do the same steps as in the guide. I am looking for advice on what could be missing?

Found out that I was missing the spring-boot-configuration-processor artifact, in the same way as the autoconfigure processor is used.
